# What is the semantical difference between reliable and trustworthy?

Tags: differences, semantics

When one literally translates the Dutch word *betrouw-baar* (dash added) one gets *trust-worthy* (dash added). But when one uses *Google translate*, it generates *reliable*.

Based on my experience with English, I would say *trustworthy* is used to characterize a human: "can you trust a human when he says something?" whereas *reliable* is more used to describe the state of an object, for instance "a reliable machine".

In Dutch the term is used to describe both persons and objects.

Is this correct? If not, what is the semantical difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you left-click on Google Translate's English translation of *betrouwbaar*, you will see a drop-down selection of possible alternative translations, including *reliable, trustworthy* and *safe.*

As you have correctly observed, *trustworthy* is usually applied to humans; *reliable* can be used both for animate and inanimate entities.

Comment: One can be trustworthy without being reliable. For instance, I may trust that my secrets are safe with you (trustworthy), but not count on you to remember to send the package I asked you to send (reliable).  IMHO trustworthy is more about one's heart being true, whereas reliable is more about one's actions matching one's promises. So I would choose the translation accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

reliable does not necessarily imply a promise given. one could just as easily rely on another without the other's given promise or even consent. so it would mean the other's actions matching one's expectations, desires or needs.
trust is more about refraining from an intentional act that would cause harm.
so, trust someone not to hurt you, but rely on someone to do something or behave in a certain manner (with or without any given consent).

Answer (score 1):

The two terms are similar and capable of being interchanged in many situations without losing much nuance, but "trustworthy" is more nuanced in the way of honesty, candidness, truth, and virtue. "Reliable" can carry more connotations with respect to abilities, capabilities, and the inherent characteristics of something.
It is true that "trustworthy" is more often applicable to human traits, but can still be relevant to anything that has the ability to deceive.

Answer (score 0):

Reliable means that a thing or a person that will give consistent results or responses when used, without fail, or without failing much.

- Our washing machines work reliably, and can be used daily for years without trouble.
- You can rely on Jack - he's only had one sick day in 27 years.

Rely, literally means 'rest on'.  You can lean on something, without it falling over.

Trustworthy is a much more emotional concept. It means 'when I put my trust in something, it's worthwhile' - I give my hope to something fulfilling my needs and it satisfies them.

- She is completely trustworthy - you can tell her anything and she will never betray your confidence.
- These golf clubs are completely trustworthy - you can rely on them to perform well.
- John is completely trustworthy - you can leave alcohol, jewellery, or money lying around the house and he will never touch anything.

Trustworthy is talking about the hopes of the user; reliable is talking about the qualities of the thing being used, itself.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trustworthy